# Mochawesome-reporter for Cypress with Typescript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, mochawesome

I have a Cypress project which uses Typescript and I want to include a reporter.

Problem is that the reporter always shows only the compiled Javascript code.

I tried to google but the only thing I found was an unanswered question on stackoverflow.
I also tried like 6 reporter, but every reporter used 'mochawesome-report-generator' as dependency or doesn't work at all.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it for me with a patch of mochawesome

1. install `patch-package`
2. in `./node_modules/mochawesome/src/mochawesome.js` I added at `runner.on('end', () => ...)` directly after `endCalled = true;`

```js
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(this.runner.suite.file), { encoding: 'utf8' }).split('\n');
const logLineIndices = fileContent.map((lineContent, lineIndex) => lineContent.match(/^\t+(it\\.only|it|only)/) ? lineIndex : undefined).filter(Boolean);

this.runner.suite.suites.forEach(suite => {
    suite.tests.forEach(test => {
        let testStartIndex = fileContent.findIndex(lineContent => lineContent.includes("'" + test.title + "'"));
        while (!logLineIndices.includes(testStartIndex) || testStartIndex < 0) {
            testStartIndex--;
        }

        if (testStartIndex < 0) return;

        const endRegex = new RegExp('^\\t{' + fileContent[testStartIndex].search(/\S|$/) + '}}?\\);\\s');
        const testEndIndex = fileContent.findIndex((lineContent, lineIndex) => lineIndex > testStartIndex && endRegex.test(lineContent));

        if (testEndIndex > testStartIndex) {
            test.body = fileContent.slice(testStartIndex, testEndIndex + 1).join('\n');
        }
    });
});
```

The regex is not the best, but its working in my cases